# How to correctly use a BUSD liquidity pool

Tags: smartcontracts, cryptocurrency, bep20

We're working on a BEP20 token and given the current market, we'd like to use a BUSD LP.

The only problem is that the reflections and other functions aren't compatible.

Transactions go through successfully, but the reflections and other functions aren't executed / distributed.

Some places I think might help:

```
interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
function factory() external pure returns (address);
function WETH() external pure returns (address);
```

Might changing WETH to something else help?

Or maybe here:

```
 IUniswapV2Router02 pancakeswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);
    _pancakeswapV2LiquidityPair = IUniswapV2Factory(pancakeswapV2Router.factory())
        .createPair(address(this), pancakeswapV2Router.WETH());
    _pancakeswapV2Router = pancakeswapV2Router;

    emit Transfer(address(0), _msgSender(), _tTotal);
}

    function addLiquidity(uint256 tokenAmount, uint256 bnbAmount) private {
    // Approve token transfer to cover all possible scenarios
    _approve(address(this), address(_pancakeswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

    // Adds the liquidity and gives the LP tokens to the owner of this contract
    // The LP tokens need to be manually locked
    _pancakeswapV2Router.addLiquidityETH{value: bnbAmount}(
        address(this),
        tokenAmount,
        0, // Take any amount of tokens (ratio varies)
        0, // Take any amount of BNB (ratio varies)
        owner(),
        block.timestamp.add(300)
    );
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help!